# Python Error: TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm learning to know how Python Dictionaries work and is writing a small program to know if the word `awesome` in the word count column, then it should return me the value.

However, it is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable
```

My `word_count` column is like below:

```
{'and': 5, 'stink': 1, 'because': 2}
{'awesome': 3, 'bad': 2}
{'mac': 5, 'awesome': 1}
```

I have created this function:

```
def awesome_count(self):
    if 'awesome' in dict:
        return dict['awesome']
    else:
        return 0
```

after then, I'm using apply function to get the count, but getting an error:

```
products['awesome'] = products['word_count'].apply(awesome_count)
```

Expecting the following answer:

```
0,3,1 i.e number of times awesome is present
```

Comment: `if 'awesome' in dict: return dict['awesome']` Where is dict defined?

Comment: do I need to pass dict as a parameter to the function?. and to answer your question, dict is not defined anywhere.

Comment: It needs to be defined. Looks like this function is part of a class and acts on the object itself? Then `dict` should be the member of your class that you want to look at.

Comment: Your code makes no sense.. what is that `self` parameter for? How is `dict` defined? What exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: @user4943236 If dict is not defined anywhere, where will the key:value pairs come from? Also consider reading a book

Comment: And again, what on earth is `product`?

Comment: @RishavKundu: my code makes no sense, that is why I'm here.

Comment: @user4943236 you don’t know what your own code is supposed to do?..

Comment: @RishavKundu: you can only downvote. Did you read the first line, that I'm learning stuff and I'm bound to make mistakes. I think, the problem is in comprehension, look at the official answer, that guy wanted to solve the problem, that why he provided the solution and guys like you can only criticize

Comment: @user4943236 i don’t mean to criticise mate, you take it wrongly. i could not understand your code (or its purpose) at all, hence i commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your idea, but I noted two things:

1. You must indent the body of your function to mark the beginning and end of it. Python should give you an error if you type the way you did here.
2. you called an apply method from the value `products['soemthing']` that seems to me to be an integer value so it does not have a 'apply' method. The `TypeError` you receive tells you to call apply in an iterable object such as a list not on an integer.

Suggestion: If you just want to write a function that returns the value associated with `awesome` in the dictionary write

```
def awesome_count(dict):
    if 'awesome' in dict:
        return dict['awesome']
    return 0
```

Then call this function directly to your dictionaries.

Comment: "dict" is a reserved keyword in Python and shouldn't be used for a parameter name

Answer (score 1):

if `products['word_count']` is a `list` of `dict`, try this:

```
products = {}
products['word_count'] = [{'and': 5,'stink': 1, 'because': 2}, 
                          {'awesome': 3, 'bad': 2}, 
                          {'mac': 5, 'awesome': 1}]

products['awesome'] = [d.get('awesome',0) for d in products['word_count']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know if I change the function definition from  `def awesome_count(self):`  to `def awesome_count(dict):` how does it impact the function? can you help me clearing this concept